# Camera picture Uri null path

Tags: android, image

In my app, I let the user the chance to get a photo and set it as profile pic. There are 2 ways for getting the photo, from the gallery, and directly taken with the camera.

I have wrote code that works with booth methods, and I have tested on a Galaxy S5 with lollipop 5.0. When testing it with a KitKat 4.4.4, it is throwing a NPE. But is throwing this NPE just when taking the photo directly from the camera.

In booth cases, this is the structure I follow:

1. Get the Uri from the onActivityResult call data.
2. Get pic orientation value (in some cases the portrait image appears rotated in the imageview).
3. Decode the bitmap to downsize it mantaining the aspect ratio.
4. Rotate the image if it has the wrong orientation.
5. Save the bitmap in the internal app data.

An this is the code for the "take photo from camera" request:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_FRAG:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap srcBmp = null;

                /*Get image orientation*/
                int orientation = getImageOrientation(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
                Log.d("IMAGE_ORIENTATION", String.valueOf(orientation));

                /*Downsize bitmap mantaining aspect ratio*/
                srcBmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(
                        selectedImageUri,
                        pic_view.getWidth(), pic_view.getHeight());

                /*Rotate image if needed*/
                if (orientation == 90) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    srcBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp, 0, 0,
                            srcBmp.getWidth(), srcBmp.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
                }
                else if (orientation == 180) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    srcBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp, 0, 0,
                            srcBmp.getWidth(), srcBmp.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
                }
                else if (orientation == 270) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    srcBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp, 0, 0,
                            srcBmp.getWidth(), srcBmp.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
                }

                /*Save bitmap in internal memory*/
                ContextWrapper cw1 = new ContextWrapper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                File directory1 = cw1.getDir("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (!directory1.exists()) {
                    directory1.mkdir();
                }
                File filepath1 = new File(directory1, "profile_pic.png");
                FileOutputStream fos1 = null;
                try {
                    fos1 = new FileOutputStream(filepath1);
                    srcBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos1);
                    fos1.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SAVE_FULL_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                /*Show image in imageview*/
                pic_view.setImageBitmap(srcBmp);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

-

```
/*Downsize the bitmap from uri*/
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Uri uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try{
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return bm;
}


public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

-

```
/*Get image orientation first from Exif info*/
public int getImageOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    int orientation = getOrientationFromExif(photoUri);
    if(orientation <= 0) {
        orientation = getOrientationFromMediaStore(context, photoUri);
    }
    return orientation;
}

private int getOrientationFromExif(Uri photoUri) {
    int orientation = -1;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                orientation = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                orientation = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                orientation = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                orientation = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("EXIF_ORIENTATION", "Unable to get image exif orientation", e);
    }
    return orientation;
}

/* normal landscape: 0
 * normal portrait: 90
 * upside-down landscape: 180
 * upside-down portrait: 270
 * image not found: -1
 */
private static int getOrientationFromMediaStore(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri, projection, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getInt(0);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

It is throwing the NPE in the line where I want to get the image orientation from the exif data, exactly where I get the Path from the uri:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
```

So I know that it must be something with the path. I have readed several posts about that kitkat returns the path in a diferent format. I have tried diferent custom getPath() methods, but always throws NPE when calling the Cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I know that it must be something with the path.

That's because it's not a filesystem path. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), and while you are handling that properly elsewhere, you are not doing so here.

You need to switch to EXIF logic that can handle an `InputStream`, such as [this code culled from the AOSP Mms app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/tree/master/camera/src/com/android/mms/exif).

Comment: So, you mean that using getPath() for the Uri isn't the right way of doing it. I'm having a look to the code that you provided, but I think that my knowledge isn't enough to understand it completely and know how to use it in my code. I would appreciate if you could guide me on how to do what you have indicated about handling the InputStream using Exif logic.